# I want to know where does the value go after deleting from an array?

Tags: arrays, c, memory

lets say I've an array

```
int size=6;
int a[size]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

and I wanted to delete k=3 element.

```
for(i=k;i<size-1;i++)
a[k]=a[k+1];
size=size-1;
```

here I've just removed the element from index k, for sure that value would not be present in the array, but if not in the array then where is the data, that value.

Comment: This doesn't re-size the array.  The last element is still there, and still has the last value it held.  If you want to resize an array, use `malloc` and `realloc` instead.

Comment: You did not _remove_ the element from the index `k`, you just _overwrote_ it  (changed its value) by _copying_ the value from the element at index `k+1` into it.

Comment: The previous value at each `a[k]` does not "go anywhere", but gets overwritten. An analogy is that you have a pile of, say, beans, and you rearrange its shape, but it's the same collection of beans. Or a box of toys: the same toys but packed in a different way. It's their *shape* that no longer exists.

Comment: @TomKarzes even if I `realloc` its just removing the element from that address, but  after removing where does that value goes.

Comment: Unrelated, but `int size=6; int a[size];` is bad practice. It uses a Variable Length Array when it in not required. VLA is an optional feature, and for example is not supported by Microsoft compilers. And is you later switch to C++, it is explicitely not supported by the C++ standard. Better to use `int a[6];` or `#define SIZE 6` `int a[SIZE];`.

Comment: This is a fundamental question, please inform yourself about dynamic memory allocation and heap memory

Comment: @Shubham was my [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280282/i-want-to-know-where-does-the-value-go-after-deleting-from-an-array#comment122451342_69280282) inadequate?

Comment: @WeatherVane Even if we overwrite the value does that mean the previous value is still there(, overwriting  means writing on previously existing value) , that means it isn't deleted yet, is there anything that justify the definition of "Delete".

Comment: It doesn't "go anywhere". That's not a good way to look at it. The bits in that memory space change; they don't go anywhere.

Comment: @ShubhamWadkar You're asking the wrong questions.  Values don't "go" anywhere.  The issue is whether the memory used to *hold* the values is reclaimed and potentially reused for something else.

Comment: @TomKarzes you got my point correctly even with improper explanation thank for that, but the question still seems unanswered, can we free that memory, I mean can delete that value that data in real, there are few software that can retain the permanently data from formatted drive.

Comment: Shubham it is *you* using the word "delete", so it's up to you to define what you mean in this context. You are asking us what it means, but only you know that.

Comment: @A.R.C. even in dynamic memory allocation when we use `free` it free the pointer, the memory allocated by pointer is freed, the pointer is made empty, but after emptying the pointer where is that data dumped, that what i want know, I am sorry if i was not able to explain my question.

Comment: The data isn't dumped. The memory becomes available for re-use. If you want to prevent residual values remaining, you can overwrite them before handing the memory back to the system.

Comment: @WeatherVane for me delete means that value is not longer existing, for example stack if we want to delete any value from stack what we do is only remove it from the stack. In real life we say if human isn't on earth surface we consider him to be dead(deleted), but the probability of him being alive as much as being dead, if he isn't on earth surface, he might be an astronaut on some space station.(I am pretty bad with example sorry for that).

Comment: The tools you are refering to are workin on a file system level (like eg. FAT) which has nothing to do with these basic lines of code which only modify RAM memory.

Comment: Hang on, please *edit the question* to clarify exactly what you mean. You commented "there are few software that can retain the permanently data from formatted drive" but that is an entirely different matter.

Comment: for now my question is how delete works, where the deleted value goes, if overwritten can it be accessed if it can be, then that must be holding on some memory, and if it is holding memory then it isn't deleted yet.

Comment: You are still asking "how delete works" but there isn't any delete operation or function in C.

Comment: @WeatherVane Iam just new to stack overflow, and just slipped to the down, back to your point if there isn't any function that means all we do is remove value from the pointer or overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is deleted.

The line `a[k]=a[k+1];` sets the value of `a[k]` to the value of `a[k+1]`.

So if the array starts with `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` and `k` is 3, then afterwards the array holds `{0,1,2,4,4,5}`.

Answer (score 3):

In C language, an array has a fixed size. That means that you can neither add nor remove elements to an array. You can only re-write them.

What is closest to an array of dynamic size is a dynamic array which can be obtained by `malloc`. It can later be resized by `realloc` but:

- the standard library if free to ignore any shrinking call and keep the array with its maximum size
- released memory can be returned to the operating system to be accessible to other processes or can remain stuck to the current process
- an extending call can involve a full copy of the existing elements

Reallocing dynamic arrays is indeed a common idiom in C language, but you must be aware of its limits an not abuse it. In your example it would be overkill.

---

Dynamic allocated memory has to be released by `free`. After calling `free`:

- the pointer keeps its previous value and is called a `dangling` pointer because it points to unallocated memory and dereferencing it explicitely invokes Undefined Behaviour (the hell for C programmers...)
- the implementation of the standard library is free to do what it wants with the released memory:

  - it can be returned to the Operating System
  - if can be *recycled* to become available to later `malloc` calls or even become no longer usable. The underlying algorithm used to manage the dynamic memory is not specified by the standard

That being said a common algorithm is to exchange *pages* of a certain size with the OS, and allocate memory for the program from those pages. The empty blocs are often handled as a list, and a new released bloc is concatenated with an adjacent free bloc to try to have as large blocs as possible. And only when a page is contained in a free bloc, it can be returned to the OS. But this is the problem of the implementer of the standard library, not the one of the C programmer.

Comment: in dynamic memory allocation when we use free it free the pointer, the memory allocated by pointer is freed, the pointer is made empty, but after emptying the pointer where is that data dumped, that what i want know, I am sorry if i was not able to explain my question.

Comment: Shubam you aren't reading the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280282/i-want-to-know-where-does-the-value-go-after-deleting-from-an-array?noredirect=1#comment122451711_69280282).

Comment: @ShubhamWadkar: please see my edit...

Comment: @SergeBallesta so according to dynamic memory allocation memory is allocated dynamically and is released after using free, I am well aware of this phenomena, the thing is when it releases memory where does the data go.

Comment: @ShubhamWadkar It goes nowhere as long as it is not overwritten. The program just no longer considers it in the program flow. Do you even know how RAM memory works in hardware?

Comment: @A.R.C. okay it's just overwritten again and again and again.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "delete" items in an array, just overwrite them with other data. C is close to the hardware and in physical RAM there is no "deleted" state of a cell, it must always hold a value.

Deleting one item is therefore done by moving all items behind the one you wish to delete one step forward (which is quite inefficient to do). The allocated size will still be the same though. So you'll need a counter variable to keep track of the actual data size used.

- Given an array `int array[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};`
- Then the number of items is `sizeof array / sizeof *array;`

  ```
  size_t items = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
  ```

  `items` will be the above mentioned counter variable.
- We wish to remove one item at a certain index:

  ```
  size_t index = 3;
  ```
- The size of the chunk behind the item you wish to remove is then expressed as:

  ```
  size_t size_to_move = (items-index-1) * sizeof *array;
  ```

  Which on a 32 bit computer is (6-3-1) * 4 = 8 bytes.
- We are moving data inside the same array, which means there are overlapping memory segments. In case of overlaps we can't use `memcpy`, so we have to used the specialized function `memmove` instead, which uses temporary buffers internally to deal with overlaps.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
  int array[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
  size_t items = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
  size_t index = 3;
  size_t size_to_move = (items-index-1) * sizeof *array;
  
  memmove(&array[index], &array[index+1], size_to_move);
  items--;

  for(size_t i=0; i<items; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 4 5
```

Note that if we don't decrease the item counter with `item--`, we would get `0 1 2 4 5 5`. The allocated array size remains `6` so we can still access the last item, and that one used to hold a `5`, so it still contains it, because items aren't actually "moved" but copied.

Comment: thanks for your time and effort, that was something new for me. But are we just overwriting here k+1th index value on k+1.